# Suggestions for creating a good chat application with comet

Tags: c#, asp.net, comet

I am trying to build a chat application using c# asp.net ajax javascript.  I heard about comet and people say that you can build a first class chat application.  Does anyone know any good tutorials on making a full built chat system in a website (using comet or not)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A blog post that I wrote some time ago (http://kboek.blogspot.com/2009/09/using-ihttpasynchandler-and.html) might give you some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a start: http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync/learn/demos/extjschat